# Make some properties optional in a TypeScript type

Tags: typescript

If I have a type with all required properties, how can I define another type with the same properties where some of it's properties are still required but the rest are optional?

For example I want a new type derived from SomeType where prop1 and prop2 are required but the rest are optional:

```
interface SomeType {
    prop1;
    prop2;
    prop3;
    ...
    propn;
}

interface NewType {
    prop1;
    prop2;
    prop3?;
    ...
    propn?;
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use combination of `Partial` and `Pick` to make all properties partial and then pick only some that are required:

```
interface SomeType {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
    propn: string;
}

type OptionalExceptFor<T, TRequired extends keyof T> = Partial<T> & Pick<T, TRequired>

type NewType = OptionalExceptFor<SomeType, 'prop1' | 'prop2'>

let o : NewType = {
    prop1: "",
    prop2: ""
}
```

Comment: For completeness: `type RequiredExceptFor<T, TOptional extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, TOptional>> & Partial<T>;` with `type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;`

Comment: There's a catch here. If the source properties are optional, say prop1 and prop2, that won't trigger any error. Wrapping Pick in Required shold do the job. `type OptionalExceptFor<T, TRequired extends keyof T> = Partial<T> & Required<Pick<T, TRequired>>;`

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderD. But for this one, I want only to mark optional what properties I want, so the rest remains the same.

Answer (score 5):

For tetter performance, in addition to [Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir)'s answer, you must do :

```
type OptionalExceptFor<T, TRequired extends keyof T = keyof T> = Partial<
  Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, TRequired>>
> &
  Required<Pick<T, TRequired>>;
```

Comment: this works for me when I tried to use the type in a spread operator into a fully required version, there Titian's above did not.

Comment: In what situations would this affect performance? Would it be compile times for typescript? Or handling big objects in editor? As I guess it has no impact on js execution?

Answer (score 5):

```
type onlyOneRequired = Partial<Tag> & {id: string}
```

In the above type, all properties of Tag are optional instead of `id` which is required.
So you can use this method and specify the required properties.

Comment: This solution does not work : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcxQbwChkTlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gBpjT7Ns9r9kEA9uAjhqGMFFA4WyKBAA2cSOQCSVZOMkgcAbQC6yAD41a8+cgC+bUsji0wACwFQxEqddII5S4EIAiShDUAZBsFoSE8hBgyOTAGAAOigCeEOQA+pxYuJjUAIJQUHDJADyEAJAACnBQYMBw8iXo2XgAfMgAZMhE5eUU1HRM0BXldo7Orlo4I14QPv6BwYEjWdxB3SPlgsKiGm7aI+Hl4a0RcYkpaZlcORjIALzI+oTnScVXq7cPTxU95Z88br8ISQXYAIgA7g5AgA3aBgyxsXpjJwuZBggBSAgcIGQfgEEDBSK23jqC0gAwgELxgQAFABKJFWCoAOjZtNelwyAMwAH5YvE3qluTc8HdqPpGYQ9BFthgBFEWfIBDgOYKudcWpgdAAGPQsnksuSKZRqelAA

Comment: My bad, it does not work with *nested* types

Comment: @cassepipe Sorry I was on a holiday
I hope the answer helped you :)

Comment: @M Fuat It did thanks. Actually I believe none of the other answers can work with *nested* types anyways.
Your answer should be the accepted one as it is the most readable in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

From this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-make-certain-properties-optional-in-typescript-9b4f8e85c5de):

We can derive the following type:

```
export type PartialPick<T, F extends keyof T> = Omit<T, F> & Partial<Pick<T, F>>;
```

F - the fields that should be made optional

T - the type

In your example:

```
type NewType = PartialPick<SomeType, 'prop3' | ... | 'propn'>
```

If you'd like to make some properties required instead of the partial use:

```
type RequiredPick<T, F extends keyof T> = Omit<T, F> & Required<Pick<T, F>>;
```

If NewType should be an interface and has additional fields besides the fields in SomeType, you can use extends from the type:

```
interface SomeType {
    prop1;
    prop2;
    prop3;
    prop4;
}
interface NewType extends PartialPick<SomeType, 'prop3' | 'prop4'> {
    prop5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
export type ContactInfoFormInput = Pick<AccountDetails, 'email' | 'phone'> &
  Pick<Profile, 'firstName' | 'lastName'> & {
    dateCreated?: Profile['dateCreated'];
  };
```

So in this example, email, phone, firstName, lastName are all required but dateCreated which also comes from the Profile base type is optional