# Type 'Pick<TTask, TId>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<TTask>' where TId extends keyof TTask

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Minimal code to reproduce the typescript error.

```
type OptionalExceptFor<T, TRequired extends keyof T> = Partial<T> &
  Pick<T, TRequired>;

function some<
  TTask extends { [id in TId]: string },
  TId extends keyof TTask
>(task: Pick<TTask, TId>): OptionalExceptFor<TTask, TId> {
  return task;
}
```

It might look insane, but I've removed everything that is not related to the error. The idea is:

- `TTask` is any interface with some property that is considered as an identifier.
- This property is passed to the generic as a type parameter, because for different `TTask` types this property may be different.
- Identifier is expected to be a `string`.
- The function gets an object that contains at least the identifier (in real scenario some other properties also, from the common ancestor of `TTask` - removed for simplicity).
- The function returns an object that is guaranteed to have the identifier required, and it may have some other properties of `TTask` but they are optional. I'm using `OptionalExceptFor` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703444/3082178.

The error is

```
Type 'Pick<TTask, TId>' is not assignable to type 'OptionalExceptFor<TTask, TId>'.
  Type 'Pick<TTask, TId>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<TTask>'.
    Type 'keyof TTask' is not assignable to type 'TId'.
      'keyof TTask' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TId', but 'TId' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
        Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'TId'.
          'string | number | symbol' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TId', but 'TId' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TId'.
              'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TId', but 'TId' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.(2322)
```

Here is the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwKIA8DGE8AYkgE4A8AKgDRSUBKEAjgK4KkQAmUEOwEKTgGcoAawggkAMzoA+KAF4oABTSlEmKvIBkAKCgqEeUVVoNmbDp1kBuXbqksUeRKihCkAWwjl9dSmhCojx8AsJQAN5QANoI3AgodACSnAC6AFzuwKQJAOZQAL7UfpQpIfyCIuKSMpQBQbqyABTAgaKZykYmdW1mKbIAlJlwrujY+ITAJBQ9QX3WkX4cwCykia1BdgW6QA).

I feel that the problem is caused by `TId extends keyof TTask`, but can’t think of any way to declare another way. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a call to the `some()` function? It looks like there's no way for the compiler to infer `TId` except as the full list of keys from `task`, which isn't your intent. Is someone supposed to manually specify the generics like `some<{a: string, b: number}, "a">(...)`? Or is the real code able to infer `TId` from another parameter you left out like `some({a: "", b: 1}, "a")`? The compiler's error message is reasonable because it can't be sure you don't do `some<{a:string,b:number}>(x)` where `x`'s type has a non-numeric `b` property. Not sure how to fix without understanding the use.

Comment: See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwKIA8DGE8AYkgE4A8AKgDRSUBKEAjgK4KkQAmUEOwEKTgGcoAawggkAMzoA+KAF4oABTSlEmKvIBkAKCgqEeUVVoNmbDp1kBuXbqksUeRKihCkAWwjl9dSmhCojx8AsJQAN5QANoI3AgodACSnAC6AFzuwKQJAOZQAL7UfpQpIfyCIuKSMpQBQbqyABTAgaKZykYmdW1mKbIAlJlwrujY+ITAJBQ9QX3WkX4cwCykia1BdgX2CfykUmgEUAAakVBomULZebQARpfXKPkFdnioV1A4madKURdQACIAXdMkDCq93sAoEgkGAREoPN5yH8HjkniCoCgWJ5bhBSIVaAC0ADmjgBnYYXCAHS3AD8VOASCICBwXCa5IMAHpOVBSE5EN4eKRSGQgA) for an example of the problem.